# How to automatically hide mode line by detecting frame size?

Tags: frames, mode-line, doom

Hide mode-line would be more compact for a narrow sub-frame like this:
[image]

For now, I'm using doom-emacs and binding keys like `SPC t m` to hide the mode-line, This just works but, I want to ask,

**Is it possible to automatically hide mode-line by detecting the current frame size, and how to?**